# Linq syntax c# to select two field from table

Tags: c#

i am writing the following linq code in c#

```
      var groupedData = from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      group b by b.Field<string>("TypeColor") into g

                      select new
                      {

                          Key = g.Key,

                          Value = g.Select(r => r.Field<int>("Price")),
                          Price = g.Select(r => r.Field<int>("Price"))

                      };

 foreach (var g in groupedData)
    {
        string s = g.Key;
}
```

how can i select two or more field from the datatable and group the table with one field.
Can any body help me?
Here dt is a datatable which is binding from database

Comment: Should you `sum`, `max`,`min`,`avg` or `top 1` to get the fields?

Comment: do u want to create a new column? use expressions for a new column. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: i want to convert the following sql statement into the linq statement "Select col1 , col2 from table1 group by col1". any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the fields if you've grouped the rows(similar as in SQL):

```
var groupedData = from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("TypeColor") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Color = g.Key,
                      PriceSum = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Price")),
                      FirstValue = g.First().Field<int>("Value")
                  };

foreach (var g in groupedData)
{
    string color = g.Color;
    Double priceSum = g.PriceSum;
    int firstValue = g.FirstValue;
}
```

Comment: hi, this code is giving me an error "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: i want to convert the following sql statement into the linq statement "Select col1 , col2 from table1 group by col1". any idea??

Comment: @user1237799: That SQL would be invalid in T-SQL (MS SQL-Server) since you need to aggregate `col2` too. But what types are `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: col1 as varchar and col 2 as int.

Comment: @user1237799: So do you want the `SUM` of `col2` for each `col1` group? You can also take the first, highest,lowest,average,count,... that's what i meant with aggregate. Or do you want to iterate every `col2` of each `col1` group in a sub-loop?